# How can I rename a file on unix using characters in filename?

Tags: unix, filenames, rename

```
I have a bunch of files in a unix directory that look like the following:

filename_1234567.txt

I need to rename them by copying the last three characters of each filename  
to the front of the filename like this:

567_filename_1234567.txt

Note: Both the filename and extension are variable.

I'm running this on a Solaris box.

Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: What shell are you using?  `echo $SHELL`

Comment: I am testing it at the command line using ksh but plan to run it as part of a bash script.

Comment: You need to test using the same shell you intend on using for production!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:

```
\ls *.txt | sed 's/\(.*\)\(...\).txt/mv \1\2.txt \2_\1.txt/' | sh
```

(probably wise to write that with `echo mv`, while you're double-checking it does what you think it does).

I can't decide if the alternative

```
sed 's/\(\(.*\)\(...\).txt\)/mv \1 \3_\2.txt/'
```

is more robust, or just way too fussy.

Comment: This worked:  \ls *.txt | sed 's/\(.*\)\(...\).txt/mv \1\2.txt \2_\1.txt/' | sh

How would it work if the extension was variable --> ls *.*  ?

Answer (score 0):

```
#for file in *_*.*
for file in `ls *_*.txt`
do
   last_3="$(echo $file | grep -o "...\...."|cut -d'.' -f1)"
   cp $file ${last_3}_${file}
done
```

Comment: What's wrong with `for file in *_*.txt`? Don't parse the output of `ls`; it's bound to give you problems...

Comment: I agree but as he's new it was a hint hint to him as he can explore more. Thanks for pointing out that

Comment: Especially "as he's new", it would be better to suggest good scripting practices, not bad ones...

Comment: Ran for loop and received this:
"grep: illegal option -- o
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . ."
NOTE: Running on Solaris box.

Comment: @BlairCombs I see. Does your solaris box have /usr/local/gnu/bin/grep (GNU grep)?